# 'No module named pyvtk' using nmagpp?

Tags: python, physics, vtk, scientific-computing

I'm running the nmag virtual machine using VMware player and I'm trying to follow the first example 'Demag field in uniformly magnetised sphere.' However, when I get to part where I try to visualize the data the command 'nmagpp --vtk sphere1.vtk sphere1' it returns an error stating that there is no module named pyvtk. According to the nmag documentation the virtual machine should contain all of the necessary tools, so does anybody know what the problem might be here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to download Pyvtk

   wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/PyVTK/PyVTK-0.4.85.tar.gz --no-check-certificate
2. decompress the file downloaded

   tar xvfz PyVTK-0.4.85.tar.gz
3. Go to the extraction directory

   cd PyVTK-0.4.85/
4. Install pyvtk (the password should be **nmag**)

   sudo python setup.py install
5. Execute your example

   cd ~/Desktop/nmag-examples-drafts/example1

   nmagpp --vtk sphere1.vtk sphere1